# Deducting doesn't work

Tags: php

I've got this script.

```
<?php   
include 'config.php'; // Mysql connection
    $cislonakupucount=$_GET['cislonakupucount'];

    $op1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `count_size` WHERE `cislonakupu`='$cislonakupucount'");

                                                            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($op1)) {
    $id=$row['idproduktu'];
                    $op=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `count_size` WHERE `cislonakupu`='$cislonakupucount' AND `idproduktu`='$id'");
                }
                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($op)) {
                        $idproduktu=$row['idproduktu'];
                        $s=$row['S']; // only number of chosen size
                        $m=$row['M'];
                        $l=$row['L'];
                        $xl=$row['XL'];
                        $vybrvel=$row['vybrvel']; // chosen size (of product)

    if($vybrvel == "S"){
                        $b=mysql_query("UPDATE `products` SET `S`=S-$s WHERE `serial`='$idproduktu'");
                    }elseif($vybrvel == "M"){
                        $b=mysql_query("UPDATE `products` SET `M`=M-$m WHERE `serial`='$idproduktu'");
                    }elseif($vybrvel == "L"){
                        $b=mysql_query("UPDATE `products` SET `L`=L-$l WHERE `serial`='$idproduktu'");
                    }elseif($vybrvel == "XL"){
                        $b=mysql_query("UPDATE `products` SET `XL`=XL-$xl WHERE `serial`='$idproduktu'");
                    }
    ?>
```

It works if "count_size" includes one row only. For example (cislonakupu=123 , S=1 , idproduktu=1).
But, if "count_size" includes two rows : For example (cislonakupu=123 , S=1 , idproduktu=1) ,(cislonakupu=123 , S=1 , idproduktu=2), mysql query deducts only one size (for example row no.1).
How to deduct it correctly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Your `while` loops aren’t nested, so your second loop will only work with the last query that the previous one executed. Why are you using two loops here anyway – instead of just looping over the records the first query returns only once …?